# Are there only finitely many number fields with given prime factors of discriminant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb P$ be a finite set of prime numbers. Is it true that there are only finitely many number fields $K$ such that $p \mid \Delta_K$ implies $p \in S$?

Comment: What about $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^r})$ with $S=\{p\}$?

Comment: Thanks. I posted a follow up question where I explained how this question here arose: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898107/maximal-extension-of-mathbb-q-unramified-outside-a-finite-set-of-primes