# Maximal extension of $\mathbb Q$ unramified outside a finite set of primes

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, discriminant, ramification

I read the beginning of chapter 1 of [Wiles paper](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/wiles.pdf) on **Modular elliptic curves and Fermat's Last Theorem**. There it says:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. Let $\Sigma$ be a finite set of primes including $p$ and let $\mathbb Q_\Sigma$ be the maximal extension of $\mathbb Q$ unramified outside this set and $\infty$.

As I saw in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897323/are-there-only-finitely-many-number-fields-with-given-prime-factors-of-discrimin) that there are infinitely many number fields that ramify in $p$ only. So what is meant here? I guess the key is $\infty$ since I don't know precicly what it means to ramify at $\infty$.

Comment: A place of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ over $\infty$ is unramified if it is real. So $\mathbb{Q}_\Sigma$ should be totally real.

Comment: May be your problem is that you expect $\mathbb{Q}_\Sigma/\mathbb{Q}$ to be finite. But it is not.

Comment: @xarles Oh yeah. That's true. I expected $\mathbb Q_\Sigma$ to be a number field.